# Solving SDE $dx_t = (A - a x_t) dt + (b) dZ_t$

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I am new to stochastic differential equations. I would like to solve something like this:

$dx_t = (A - a x_t) dt + (b) dZ_t$

where:

$A = \frac{ - \delta k }{\delta + a} $

The solution is:

$x_t = e^{-at} x_0 + (1 - e^{-at}) \frac{A}{a} + b \int_0^t e^{a(u-t)} dZ_t$

Could someone help me understand what integrating factor I should use?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: Added my attempt.

Comment: Looks ok, except that $\int_0^te^{au}\,du=(e^{at}-1)/a$. This gives your the missing $A/a$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP only had a minor error that was easy to solve.

Comment: I moved the solution to the answers and I will close the question in two days if it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integration factor $W_t = e^{a t} x_t$. By Ito's lemma:
\begin{align}
dW_t &= a e^{a t} x_t dt + e^{a t} dx_t \\
dW_t &= a e^{a t} x_t dt + e^{a t} ((A - a x_t) dt + b dZ_t) \nonumber \\
dW_t &= (a e^{a t} x_t + A e^{a t} - a e^{a t} x_t) dt + b e^{a t} dZ_t \nonumber \\
dW_t &= A e^{a t} dt + b e^{a t} dZ_t \nonumber
\end{align}
Integrating both sides:
\begin{align}
\int_0^t d(e^{a u} x_u) &= A \int_0^t e^{a u} dt + b \int_0^t e^{a u} dZ_u \\
e^{a t} x_t &= x_0 + \frac{A}{a} (e^{a t} - 1) + b \int_0^t e^{a u} dZ_u \nonumber \\
x_t &= e^{-a t} x_0 + \frac{A}{a} (1 - e^{- a t}) + b \int_0^t e^{a (u-t)} dZ_u \nonumber
\end{align}